# how to write code for a button in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to write a math code for a button for Visual Studios 2013 using C# I'm still new to programming so the concept is still pretty far out to me. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Start with pretty much any tutorial for the technology you're using.  (WPF, Windows Store Apps, WinForms, ASP.NET, etc.)  There are many introductory guides to help you.

Comment: Do you need help with **wiring up a Click() event handler** for your Button?...or help with **the actual Math** in the handler?  Either way, we need more DETAILS about your setup and what you're trying to accomplish!

Comment: Please note that there are two similar but different .Net UI frameworks: Forms and WPF. Your question cannot be complete without that information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio or Sharp Develop, place the button on your form, double click the button - the IDE will take you to the button click event. Inside the event you can do one of two things.

**1:** Write your calculation method in the button event.

```
void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
myTextbox.Text = .. do some math calculation. ;
}
```

**2:** Write a separate method to perform the calculation and Call that method from with in your Button Click event .

```
void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Will throw an exception if either Text entry is not a number! 
myTextbox.Text = CalculateMath((double)myTextEntryA.Text , (double)myTextEntryB.Text)  ;
}

double CalculateMath(double valueA, double valueB)
{
   return valueA * valueB;
}
```